# Running a Packer script in a Jenkins pipeline?

Tags: jenkins-pipeline, packer

Packer v1.6.6

I have the following Packer template, which creates an AMI for Jenkins. As you can see, it has `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable.

```
{
  "variables" : {
    "aws_access_key" : "{{ env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY` }}",
    "aws_secret_key" : "{{ env `AWS_SECRET_KEY` }}",
    "ssh_private_key" : "{{ env `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` }}",
    "aws_ami_us_east_1" : "{{ env `AWS_BASE_AMI` }}",
    "jenkins_master_image_version" : "{{ env `JENKINS_MASTER_IMAGE_VERSION` }}"
  },
  "builders" : [
    "ssh_username" : "ec2-user",
    "ssh_keypair_name" : "my-key-pair",
    "ssh_private_key_file" : "{{ user `ssh_private_key` }}",
    ...
  ],
  "provisioners": []
}
```

Now I have a Jenkins pipeline that uses the template. I've stored the SSH private key file in my credentials plugin. You see where I set the `SSH_PRIVATE_KEY` variable used by the Packer template.

```
stage("Create Jenkins AMI") {
  steps {
    script {
      withCredentials([file(credentialsId: "my-key-pair-pem", variable: "SSH_PRIVATE_KEY")]) {
        dir("$env.WORKSPACE/deployment/jenkins/packer") {
          sh """
            export AWS_BASE_AMI=ami-123456abcdef \
            && export JENKINS_MASTER_IMAGE_VERSION=$env.JENKINS_VERSION \
            && packer build jenkins-ami-master.json
          """
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and when I run the job, it creates the temporary instance to run my provisioners, but it fails to SSH to it. I get

```
+ export AWS_BASE_AMI=ami-0be2609ba883822ec
+ export JENKINS_MASTER_IMAGE_VERSION=lts
+ packer build jenkins-ami-master.json
[1;32mamazon-ebs output will be in this color.[0m

[1;32m==> amazon-ebs: Prevalidating AMI Name: packer-jenkins-master-somedate[0m
[0;32m    amazon-ebs: Found Image ID: ami-123456abcedf[0m
[1;32m==> amazon-ebs: Using existing SSH private key[0m
[1;32m==> amazon-ebs: Launching a source AWS instance...[0m
[1;32m==> amazon-ebs: Adding tags to source instance[0m
[0;32m    amazon-ebs: Adding tag: "Name": "packer-builder-jenkins-master"[0m
[0;32m    amazon-ebs: Instance ID: i-0ceb4376846c69[0m
[1;32m==> amazon-ebs: Waiting for instance (i-0ceb4376846c69) to become ready...[0m
[1;32m==> amazon-ebs: Using ssh communicator to connect: 10.23.x.x[0m
[1;32m==> amazon-ebs: Waiting for SSH to become available...[0m
[1;31m==> amazon-ebs: Timeout waiting for SSH.[0m
[1;32m==> amazon-ebs: Terminating the source AWS instance...[0m
[1;32m==> amazon-ebs: Cleaning up any extra volumes...[0m
[1;32m==> amazon-ebs: No volumes to clean up, skipping[0m
[1;31mBuild 'amazon-ebs' errored: Timeout waiting for SSH.[0m

==> Some builds didn't complete successfully and had errors:
--> amazon-ebs: Timeout waiting for SSH.
```

What is the proper way to make packer use my SSH key credential in my pipeline?

**NOTE** I'm very sure I'm using the correct ssh credentials because I can manually ssh to the temporary instance using the same credentials. Also, I can execute that same CLI on my local terminal and it works.

**UPDATE**. Seems like I need to somehow pass Packer the option `-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no`, but I don't see that in the [SSH Communicator](https://www.packer.io/docs/communicators/ssh) docs.

Comment: Try setting `PACKER_LOG=1` in the pipeline, trigger the pipeline again, and see specifically why the ssh fails. Also, it would probably be easier to use the `source_ami_filter` in the Packer template than the AWS CLI in JP.

Comment: Good tip on the `source_ami_filter` setting.

Comment: Adding PACKER_LOG=1 didn't really give any more insight on the failure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was using the wrong `security_group` for my Packer `builder`. It works on my machine, but Jenkins slaves use a different security group. Once I set it to that SG, it worked.